# Does this question about glasses serve any historically significant function?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38299/do-computer-glasses-work?rq=1

Does the above provide any reason why I should not delete it?

Comment: Interesting, I've always spent a lot of time in front of a screen, and always gotten migraines. I wonder if getting anti-glare on my glasses would help... will ask at next eye appointment. So I found the question and answer useful, although I suppose it would be off-topic with today's scope.

Comment: @Rachel ... because there *is* a place to ask that question from experts who know the answer and the question isn't unique to programmers (one could ask the exact same question on Gaming.SE or Graphic Design). That it was asked here is a stretch of scope even in the days of old. "... as a programmer" was always frowned upon.

Comment: @Rachel side note - I have for *years* first thing when I get a new monitor: Go to menu, brightness down to ~15-20, contrast down to ~40-60. It looks *really* dark at first because you just changed it, but after a day you don't even notice. Makes an enormous difference IME, anybody running a full-bright monitor and staring at it all day long is absolutely killing their eyes for no reason.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 6):

Delete it.

The links are broken. If you dig hard enough you can find the proper link on think geek to "Gunnar MLG Phantom Gaming Glasses" and while Steelseries doesn't list it anymore if you search for Steelseries scope you will find... "Gunnar Optiks" on amazon.

The answer boils down to product review and health claims. We do the former poorly and are not properly trained to be able to *expertly* (sure, anecdotally - but people come here for answers from experts on the subject) answer questions about [eystrain when looking at computers](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers)... which has a tag over on Health.SE for it.

It is far too old to migrate (not that Health would want answers from a bunch of techies that know nothing about actual optometry and if there is any veracity to the claims). It is full of conflicting anecdotes on a topic that isn't on topic.

Delete it.

If you feel that the *question* has some merit on the network, rework it into a new question on Health.SE so that the network as a whole can benefit from answers from experts on the subject.